# Different Glyphicons on Chrome desktop and real mobile device

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, mobile, glyphicons

I have very different presentations of Glyphicons on a Desktop display and on an real mobile device. It looks as follows:

[image]

On the left you see Chromes mobile view and the right side is a real mobile device screenshot. Why is the right side messed up?

I am using font awesome icons with a bootstrap framework (Froundry) like this:

```
<i class="icon fa fa-wifi icon"></i>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the error:

You have to have the folder `fonts` which contain `fontawesome-webfont.woff` and other files, because `font-awesome.css` links to this files.